# Long lived thread doesn't call performSelectorOnMainThread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, nsthread, nsobject

I have a worker thread that I keep alive through a loop that's controlled by a flag. I need the thread to stay alive for the length of my application as it opens a permanent connection to a remote server.

I fire up that thread and call several methods on it with:

`[worker performSelector:@selector(getBusy) onThread:worker withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];`

This seems to work fine and the method is called. At some point in `getBusy` I try to call a method in the main thread with:

`[delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(gotBusy) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO`

where delegate is a reference to the class that starts the separate thread.

The problem is that `gotBusy` never gets called on the main thread. I've peppered it with NSLog() statements and I can't see them printed on the console.

What should I be looking for to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure `delegate` is not nil.   Secondly, make sure your main event loop is not blocked and not running in a modal mode.

Comment: Yes, the main even loop was sleeping. Your comment made a lightbulb go on in my head.

Comment: Excellent -- note that you should never block or sleep the main thread. You should also avoid scheduling lots of fine grained events (like, say, a timer that goes off every 1/10th of a second to poll for data).

Comment: This is a unit test. I had the sleep being called while a flag was set to false and didn't realise that would block the background thread from being able to call the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you never assigned `delegate`, so you're calling `performSelectorOnMainThread` on a nil object? You could try setting `waitUntilDone` to `YES` so your worker thread will block and let the delegate do its work.

Comment: Nope, delegate is not nil. I NSLog it before calling that method. But good idea, I'll tell it to wait.